# ROS call-back function doesn't functionate

Tags: ros

I met this problem when I was tring to create a new topic called "/mobile_base/sensors/switch1", I set the publisher and subscriber and the call-back function. But when I run`rostopic echo /mibile_base/sensors/switch1`, I can't get any info from this topic.

My definition is :

```
ros::Publisher stop_switch_state_publisher;
stop_switch_state_publisher = nh.advertise<robot_msgs::StopSwitch>("sensors/switch1",100);

ros::Subscriber stop_switch_state_subscriber;
stop_switch_state_subscriber = nh.subscribe("swnsors/switch1",10,&BaseRos::subScribeStopSwitchState,this);

void subscribeStopSwitchState(const robot_msgs::StopSwitchPtr &msgs);
void BaseRos::subscribStopSwitchState(const robot_msgs::StopSwitchPtr &msg){
    ROS_INFO("subscribeStopSwitchState worked!");
    if(ros::ok()){
       ROS_INFO("getting into if...");
       BaseState：：Data = mobile_base.getBaseStateData();
       msg.state = data.hard_stop;
       stop_switch_publisher.publishing(msg);
    }
return;
}
```

I checked "rostopic list", I can see the topic was there, and used"rostopic info /mobile_base/sensors/switch" got
Publishers:

- /mobile_base_nodelet_manager(http:192.168.66.20:41251)
  Subscribers:
- /mobile_base_nodelet_manager(http:192.168.66.20:41251)

Comment: can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also the `CMakelists.txt`. There is also a typo in your callback ... `swnsors/switch1` instead of `sensors/switch1`

Comment: You define `stop_switch_state_publisher` and try to publish with `stop_switch_publisher`. It shouldn't even build or this is typo?